# Como pegar valor de RadioButtonFor através de FormCollection e salvar em BD SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html5, razor

Possuo um model com vários booleanos, preciso pegar os valores deles através de um FormCollection e salvar no banco de dados SQL (não aceita boolean, por isso o campo esta como bit).

Minha View:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sex,"false", false)F
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sex,"true", true)M               
</div>
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
        {
            var pSimpleUser = new SimpleUserr()
            {
                IdSimpleUser = 0,                    
                Sex = Convert.ToBoolean (form["sex"]),
            };
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (SimpleUserDAO dao = new SimpleUserDAO())
                    if (dao.SaveSimpleUser(pSimpleUser))
                    {
                        ViewBag.AlertMessage = "Salvo Com Sucesso";
                        return View();
                    }
            }
            ViewBag.AlertMessage = "Ocorreu um problema ao salver";
            return View(pSimpleUser);
        }

    }
}
```

Função com a montagem do comando para a Procedure:

```
    public bool SaveSimpleUser(SimpleUserr pSimpleUser)
            {
                if (pSimpleUser !=null)
                {
                    using (_context)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveSimpleUser");
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idSimpleUser", pSimpleUser.IdSimpleUser);                        
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", pSimpleUser.Sex);
pSimpleUser.IsPaceMaker);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        this._context.ExecuteProcedure(cmd);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Cara, você devia pensar seriamente em abandonar o uso do `FormCollection` em prol de usar um objeto tipado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A conversão de `Boolean` para `bit` é transparente. Não sei como está sua procedure, mas se o parâmetro `@sex` é um `bit`, esta declaração:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", pSimpleUser.Sex);
```

Funciona sem problemas.

Essa abordagem não está de todo correta. No seu lugar, eu definiria um `Enum` para `Sex`:

```
public enum Sex {
    Male, 
    Female
}
```

O Model teria uma coluna com o tipo `Sex`:

```
public Sex Sex { get; set; }
```

A View então ficaria assim:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sex, Enums.Sex.Female) Female
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Sex, Enums.Sex.Male) Male
</div>
```

E a parametrização da `procedure` ficaria:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", (int)pSimpleUser.Sex);
```